# Ruby: matching a string against another object that may be a string or regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, string, comparison

I'm writing a routine that compares a string against a list of objects, each of which may be either another string or a RegExp. Is there an elegant, ruby-centric way to handle this?

For now, I'm doing something like this:

```
def compare(str, thelist)
  thelist.any? do |item|
    case str
      when item then true
      else false
    end
  end
end

if compare("The String I am testing", ['I am not', /string/i])
  # got a match
```

This seems to work well enough, but it feels a bit too hackerish and long winded for my tastes, so I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do it.  (I'm not interested in using something like instance_of? - I came up with this solution because instance_of? is too ugly.)

Working with Ruby 2.2.2

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Testing for types always seems to me like an indication that something is wrong from a design standpoint, so I avoid it when I can, especially when there is a more natural way to handle things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shortened version of your approach:

```
def compare(str, thelist)
  thelist.any? { |item| item.match(str) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify thus:

```
def compare(str, thelist)
  thelist.any? { |item| item === str }
end
```

Comment: This also does the trick - thanks!  (I accepted Zoran's answer, but this is just as good.)